# Javascript: Shorter a if ( ... or ...) condition

Tags: javascript

```
if (args.join(" ").toLowerCase() === "are you" || args.join(" ").toLowerCase() === "are you doing")
```

As you can see, I am using two very similar lines with an or case. Is there a shorter way to do this ?

Comment: If you want to check for either of the conditions, then yes you need the comparison

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
["are you", "are you doing"].includes(args.join(" ").toLowerCase())
```

The benefits of this solution is that `args.join(" ").toLowerCase()` is only executed once and that it's non-verbose while still being expressive and easily understandable.
It's also easily scalable. If you have more strings you want to validate against, just add those strings to the array.

Comment: I like this better than my own answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to rewrite a complex OR condition.

It allows you to add an arbitrary number of check values without repeating 
yourself too much.

```js
if (['are you', 'are you doing'].some(i => i === 'are you doing')) {
  console.log('passes')
}

if (['are you', 'are you doing'].some(i => i === 'are you')) {
  console.log('passes')
}
```

Comment: did you mean `i === args.join(" ").toLowerCase()`?

Comment: Yes, I intentionally omitted that to make my example more concise.

Answer (score 1):

Less readable, var `lc` defined in `if`:

```
if ((lc = args.join(" ").toLowerCase()) === "are you" || lc === "are you doing"){

}
```

Comment: this doesn't cover the `"doing"` case. Will match `'are you undoing'`

Answer (score 1):

Since your values are similar/related and are strings, I would go with a regex

```js
function test(...args){
    return /are you( doing)?/.test(args.join(" "))
}
  
  
  console.log(test("are", "you", "doing"))
  console.log(test("are", "you"))
  console.log(test("are", "yo"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do the joining and casing beforehand:

```
let lc = args.join(" ").toLowerCase();
if(lc === "are you" || lc === "are you doing"){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable say, `text` to hold the lowercase value and shorten your code and also reduce the `join()` operation to execute only once.

```
var text = args.join(" ").toLowerCase();
if (text === "are you" || text === "are you doing"){
  ...
}
```

And looking at the code it seems like `are you` is what you need to check at highest level so you can also use `indexOf()` to check that text value only like

```
var text = args.join(" ").toLowerCase();
if (text.indexOf("are you") !== -1){
  ...
}
```

Comment: That's what I have mentioned `
You can use a variable say, text to hold the lowercase value and shorten your code and also reduce the join() operation to execute only once.

var text = args.join(" ").toLowerCase();
if (text === "are you" || text === "are you doing"){
  ...
}
And looking at the code it seems like are you is what you need to check at highest level so you can also use indexOf() to check that text value only like` and I did not say `use this`